# How should I repair a gap between a window and the trim?

Tags: repair

New home owner here. Thank you for reading my post!

I just purchased my house about 3 months ago. I noticed a gap on the right side of the window frame outside of the house. I'm not sure what caused this or how to fix it. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

gap:

[image]

Comment: That's not the window frame. That's just siding trim.

Answer (score 2):

The good news is that the gap is limited to a small area of the window.   Possibly it got wet inside and the wood warped a bit. Hence the massive application of caulk.  Maybe the previous owners didn't always shut the window when it rained.

I would re-caulk it and paint it.  It doesn't look structural.

Comment: That gap isn't structural, but it could be a symptom of structural settling around the window header. It's worth keeping an eye on, and watch for other signs inside, above, and below.

Comment: I'm not sure what shutting the window would have to do with it since this appears to be the exterior trim.

Comment: If you leave a window open, water gets into the structure and can migrate up/down/sideways.  People don't generally caulk _inside_ their houses!